# Typescript - Extending class with type

Tags: javascript, typescript

Typescript newbie here.
Let's say I have a type coming from a library that looks like this:

```js
type FooType {
  name: string;
  // Has much more attributes in real life
}
```

I now want to define a class called `Foo` like this:

```js
import { FooType } from 'my-library';

class Foo {
  constructor(data: FooType) {
    Object.assign(this, data);
  }
}
```

With this code, I'm able to define a foo instance, yet I have an issue with autocomplete:

```js
const foo = new Foo({ name: 'foo name' });
// Typing in foo.name does not bring any type information about the "name" attribute
```

Is there a way I can make a class automatically "inherit" all attributes from a type without having to type them manually?

**Edit** after being marked as duplicate:

What I want to achieve is to avoid manually typing attributes that are already existing on a type.

Thanks to @Phil I've been provided an answer that mentions this as an ongoing issue within Typescript:
https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26792

What I will do for now is the following:

```
class Foo {
  constructor(public _data: FooType)
    Object.assign(this, _data);
  }

  get() {
    return this._data;
  }
}

const foo = new Foo({ name: 'Bar' });
foo.get().name; // After typing "foo.get()" the autocomplete works properly.
```

Comment: You mean `class Foo implements FooType { … }`?

Comment: Follow this issue ~ [Javascript: Object.assign to assign property values for classes is not respected #26792](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26792)

Comment: Try this [code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?module=1&ssl=7&ssc=11&pln=7&pc=21#code/PTAEEsFsAcHsCcAuoDeoBitYBUCe0BTUAX1ADN5ZJQBySXAWgBtwAjeAQ3lxoG4AofuAB2iAvDIcAxkUw58RFP1ChhHSAQBcoAM6J4IgOb9igqUw46dGLBBhMCG0dbl5CqQSugBXViymq6gQAhNp6BsLGyqBSsMLh3lKICAAUACYciBzargoAlB4qKgDyrABWBEkAdJY64IbCKYgAFuA6ADSgGVl50aam-LHxyGS2ALyqBADuNrApaGoa2jSjsIEaNCR5AoNxOrAOVUywhimrVYsEvUA)

Comment: @Asleepace I want to avoid defining these e.g. "public name: string" for all properties defined in the FooType. The only way I was managed to avoid it was with `constructor(public data: FooType)` yet then the properties are available under e.g. `foo.data.name` instead of `foo.name`

Comment: @Phil This is helfpul. As far as I understand – this is an issue with Typescript, with a few, messy, workarounds

Comment: @mdmb you could use the `Partial<FooType>` keyword

Comment: @mdmb or you could cast `as FooType` which seems to work as well [code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?module=1#code/PTAEEsFsAcHsCcAuoDeoBitYBUCe0BTUAX1ADN5ZJQBySXAWgBtwAjeAQ3lxoG4AofuAB2iAvDIcAxkUw58RFP1ChhHSAQBcoAM6J4IgOb9igqUw46dGLKmWgpsYXvgBXKYgQAKACYdEHNpyeIQAlHYqKgDyrABWBB4AdJY64IbCXogAFuA6ADSgfgGh9qam-I7OyGS2ALyqBADuNrBeaGoa2jQ1sKrqBDQk4ZYtIQRmTjqwTASJTLCGXj2JHQQlQA)

Comment: @Asleepace That's a good idea – tried that, yet it starts to complain as soon as you add new stuff to the `Foo` class. The workaround that is to cast it as e.g. `[...] as Foo & Partial<FooType>` yet I think about it as a bad developer experience, as you have to remember about casting every time you create a new `foo`.

Answer (score -1):

> ***Note***: this is just a workaround and doesn't fix the underlying issue with using Object.assign() in the constructor with TypeScript.
>
> https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16672

**Update**: this question definitely lead me down quite the rabbit and I wasn't quite happy with my previous response so here is something I think would work better for solving these two items:

- Creating a class which extends an object
- Allowing TypeScript to still do its thing

**Step One**: use the typescript [mixin pattern](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/mixins.html) to return an anonymous class with the properties of a generic object `T`:

```
function GenericBase<T>(data: T) {
  return class {
    constructor() {
      Object.assign(this, data)
    }
  } as ({
      new (...args: any[]): T;
  })
}
```

Now we have an anonymous function with a constructor which is then casted as a class that returns our generic object `T`.

**Step Two**: Note that we don't need to touch the above code we just need to extend it, so for OP's example we would do this:

```
class MyClass extends GenericBase(foo) {

  constructor() {
    super()
  }

  greet() {
     return `Hello, ${this.name}!`
  }
}
```

**More examples**:

```
const myClass = new MyClass()
console.log(myClass.name)       // bar
console.log(myClass.greet())    // Hello, bar!


function doSomethingWithFoo(someFoo: Foo) {
  // example method that only takes types Foo
}

doSomethingWithFoo(myClass)
```

[Try it on the TypeScript playground!](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=41&ssc=47&pln=39&pc=1#code/MYewdgziA2CmB0w4EMBOAKAlAWAFB4HoCACWAD2QFsAHOYgFwE9rZjkwATYkAIwCtYwesQBmqEJQYALAJaoOAWmpomePDLD1YqEcmCsAYiBDEA3nmLEwVWAC5iEeqg0BzPAF81uUJGEjj9kYmALxmFlY29gDkPGhRHl6EJMCosMhabMQusGDaMsDESMgQEMQA7jL0UtKsvAJCpdTiLKj0MrAQXiIArmBCMuDEAOI5ecAAQsWwADwAKgB86BzpyPazmGG4lqn03ahghdDFpeZbloXgjqjdQiAYG6fn5wDy-IL08McyLmDoVTIQAA0xGW9GQODOlk8Z3cbFK6EeTyssDKxHQ8AxaBcEHs7EYAG0ALqYNYAbnC7gh0KSVhAqLKrGA7FIZC0nBqxFiEEZRxKxGgMgA1qwoF4inyALKMADCvNK5DZHFKI1yzgmU3Q-hADy8lh8Vxu9DuWE2Twg3RaWApuqyqVg9BNiO29r2BwABgAJWDQaAgYEAElM-wg8GslFg7gAhG7rbhqd5LsJKDK5cRQrlUVLZccrQnIDAEL6XOhk9mSqGbBskcQiJy0Hh9QX4EWSynjvAXHaHZgq5Za16fX666hI0A)

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem to "*make a class automatically "inherit" all attributes from a type without having to type them manually*", does it? A `GenericSubClass` or `ProxySubclass` instance is still not compatible with `FooType`, is it?

Comment: The proxy appears superfluous, incomplete and inefficient, slowing down all code that uses the object created by `.new()`. Wouldn't `return Object.assign(newClassInstance, data) as ProxySubClass & FooType;` achieve basically the same?

Comment: @Bergi the difference here is that the proxy will lookup the property on the sub-class first before the parent class, which allows us to override properties and methods vs. just using `Object.assign`.

Comment: If that is what you want to achieve, you could also just loop over the data and copy only those properties that do not already exist on the target.

Comment: @Bergi this way we also retain the base-class values which can be used if we decide to override them, such as adding `Sir ${name}` to the name property. The `getter`'s & `setter`'s first do a lookup on the sub-class before checking the base class which is more similar to the prototype chain vs. merging objects conditionally.

Comment: All of this could be achieved statically as well, without a proxy. But I really doubt that the OP events wants this.

Comment: @Bergi I'm sure there are several different ways to achieve something like this, but I don't think there is anything wrong with using a proxy sparingly.